# Printing single bib entry in a section other than references

Tags: bibtex

Traditionally we use \cite{} to print a list of cited references from a .bib file at the end of document.

Apart from this i need to print one entry in a section (say above reference section).

e.g. I need something like this

Paper published

1. A.dan, i am best, in: journal of.........

References (list of cited references)

1.

2.

3 A.dan, i am best, in: journal of.........

Answer (score 2):

Sorry for bothering, Found the answer from a friend

```
\usepackage{bibentry}

\nobibliography*            %% this line tells latex to reuse bib entries from bib file


\bibentry{key}
```